# When we are running script first time script running properly but next time system throwing error file got corrupted

Tags: selenium-webdriver

First time script running successful but next time getting error file got corrupted.

Comment: Welcome to the site! We'd need more information about your problem, so we can help. Please provide details about the script, and the files.

Comment: That is good practice to clean up but what could be the reason file got corrupted.

Comment: We wrote script which reading and writing data from excel. Script running property 3 -4 time but next time    excel input data also getting deleted and system throws error message File got corrupted.

Comment: @Daven We'd still need to actually see the script, we already know you have some script, but we need to see how it looks like.

Answer (score 1):

Start your test with a clean-up. For me it is a best practise to set the state of the environment under test. This might mean deleting some files or database records.

Now it could be a defect, if you expect the same script to be runnable over and over again.

Comment: And end each test with a cleanup as well, this way you will cover failures at both ends. A cleanup doesn't have to actually clean things up but mainly verify if something is needed

Comment: Thanks Niel for your guidance